# Python - dynamically create equations from a dictionary

Tags: python, sympy

I create a dictionary from values I get from a database that fit certain criteria. Therefore I don’t know beforehand neither the number nor the values of the elements in the dictionary.

For example, I get something like this:

`ditc1 = {"P01":{"F1":0.4,"P02":0.6}, "P02":{"F2":0.3, "P03":0.7}, "P03":{"F3":0.2, "P02":0.8}}`

What I would like to do is to dynamically create mathematical equations from this elements like this:…

P01 = 0.4*F1 + 0.6*P02

P02 = 0.3*F2 + 0.7*P03

P03 = 0.2*F3 + 0.8*P02

I need the references across the equations to stay the same (e.g P02 in the first equation is P02 from the second equation), so I can solve those equations with regard to the P0X elements.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to worry about re-creating `Symbol` objects for your variables. SymPy will create *singleton* objects for you, each time you call `Symbol('P01')` the same single object is returned:

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> p = Symbol('P01')
>>> p
P01
>>> p is Symbol('P01')
True
```

So just convert your structure to SymPy objects directly and SymPy will know that `P02` is the same symbol in both the `P02 = ...` equality expression and the `0.6*P02` multiplication.

Because you presumably can have an arbitrary number of elements in the nested dictionary, you can use `sympy.Add()` to build the addition from any number of components. I'm going to assume you want to record the `=` symbol in the equation too, so use [`sympy.Eq()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#equals-signs) for that:

```
from sympy import Symbol, Add, Eq

expressions = []
for p, equation_components in ditc1.items():
    p = Symbol(p)
    expression = []
    for name, multiplier in equation_components.items():
        expression.append(Symbol(name) * multiplier)
    expressions.append(Eq(p, Add(*expression)))
```

This produces

```
>>> from sympy import pprint
>>> for expr in expressions:
...     pprint(expr)
...
P₀₁ = 0.4⋅F₁ + 0.6⋅P₀₂
P₀₂ = 0.3⋅F₂ + 0.7⋅P₀₃
P₀₃ = 0.2⋅F₃ + 0.8⋅P₀₂
```

If you want to play with this [here is a SymPy Live version](https://live.sympy.org/?evaluate=ditc1%20%3D%20%7B%22P01%22%3A%7B%22F1%22%3A0.4%2C%22P02%22%3A0.6%7D%2C%20%22P02%22%3A%7B%22F2%22%3A0.3%2C%20%22P03%22%3A0.7%7D%2C%20%22P03%22%3A%7B%22F3%22%3A0.2%2C%20%22P02%22%3A0.8%7D%7D%0A%23--%0Aexpressions%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Afor%20p%2C%20equation_components%20in%20ditc1.items%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20p%20%3D%20Symbol%28p%29%0A%20%20%20%20expression%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20name%2C%20multiplier%20in%20equation_components.items%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20expression.append%28Symbol%28name%29%20*%20multiplier%29%0A%20%20%20%20expressions.append%28Eq%28p%2C%20Add%28*expression%29%29%29%0A%23--%0Aexpressions%0A%23--%0A).

Answer (score 0):

I was just thinking about converting a simple dictionary of symbols and expressions to a list of equations like

```
>>> d2e = lambda d: [*map(lambda i:Eq(*i), d.items())]
>>> d2e({x:y+1, z:2})
[Eq(x, y + 1), Eq(z, 2)]
```

That could be used with your dictionary by turning it into a sympified form (which can be done with a call to `Dict`:

```
>>> s = Dict(dict1)
```

Then the dictionaries appearing as values can be converted to expressions:

```
>>> s = {k: Add(*[s*n for s,n in v.items()]) for k,v in s.items()}; s
{P01: 0.4*F1 + 0.6*P02, P02: 0.3*F2 + 0.7*P03, P03: 0.2*F3 + 0.8*P02}
```

And then the dictionary can be converted to a list of expressions; the first of which is shown:

```
>>> d2e(s)[:1]
[Eq(P01, 0.4*F1 + 0.6*P02)]
```

(And those values can be solved to give a dictionary where values are independent of the `P` values with a call like `solve(d2e(s), list(s), dict=True)`.)